# Which pins does STM32F03 use for USART?

Tags: stm32, uart, pinout

I've looked through both the datasheet and the reference manual, but I can't figure out which pins can be used with the USART.

I don't want to use the STM32CubeMX for this.

Comment: It's in the datasheet (product specification), chapter 4 "Pinouts and pin descriptions". It depends on the exact model / package.

Comment: Right, thank you.

Comment: Is there even such a part? Seems you are missing a digit.  Anyway whatever it is the options are in the data sheet.

Comment: @Codo, your are right. I googled the datasheet and found the chip has many Pxy pins which I think can do anything ST wishes: (1) STM32F03 pinouts: https://i.imgur.com/XzNZsY7.jpghttps://i.imgur.com/XzNZsY7.jpg

Comment: I doesn't sound as if you have already figured out the specific pin numbers. See my answer.

Comment: @Codo, Ha yes, I am just a lazy. casual hobbyist. I did not read the datasheet too carefully. You mentioned "Chapter 4", so I stopped at Chapter 4. You reminded me how once an ex customer complained to my ex boss about me. "He is just a square rolling stone, kick it once, it rolls one step and immediately, stops, waiting for another kick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to determine the UART pins, assuming you have a STM32F030R8Tx in a LQFP64 package:

Open the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f030f4.pdf) on go to *Table 8. STM32F0x0 USART implementation*. It lists what USARTs the chip has. In this particular case: *USART1* and *USART2*.

[image: STM32F0x0 USART implementation]

All the Pxx pins are GPIO pins by default. USART features can be routed to them using the alternate functions. So the easiest way to determine the USART pins, is to check *Table 12. Alternate functions selected through GPIOA_AFR registers for port A* and the following tables.

[image: Alternate functions selected through GPIOA_AFR registers for port A]

[image: Footnotes]

If you search for "USART1" and check for the *(2)* marker, you'll find:

- TX: PA2, PA9, PA14, PB6
- RX: PA3, PA10, PA15, PB7
- CTS: PA0, PA11
- RTS: PA1, PA12
- CK: PA4, PA8

You'll find similar results for USART2. You will need to configure the pins alternate function in order to route USART signals to the desired pin. Each USART function (RX, TX etc.) can go to 2 to 4 different pins.

Additional pin information can be found in *Table 11. STM32F030x4/6/8/C pin definitions.